# How to show standard deviation by calendar month using groupby and plot it?

Tags: python, statistics, data-visualization, kaggle

The dataset (df) I am using is based on the Avocado Price Dataset which can be found below:

https://www.kaggle.com/neuromusic/avocado-prices

I am trying to plot the price volatility (standard deviation) of avocados, by year, month and avocado type, like the picture below

[image: Price Volatility Chart]

I tried to code it like this but I keep getting the error 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float:

```
month_dict = {1 : 'Jan', 
          2: 'Feb', 
          3: 'Mar', 
          4: 'Apr', 
          5: 'May', 
          6: 'Jun', 
          7: 'Jul', 
          8: 'Aug', 
          9: 'Sep', 
          10: 'Oct', 
          11: 'Nov', 
          12: 'Dec'}

cal_years =[2015, 2016, 2017]
types = ['conventional','organic']
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index).month
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,3, figsize=(15,10), sharey=True)
for type in types:
    for axy in range(2):
        for axx in range(3):            
                df_plot = df[(df['type'] == types[axy]) & (df['year'] == cal_years[axx])]
                df_plot = df_plot.groupby('Month', as_index=False)['AveragePrice'].std()                
                df_plot['Month'] = df_plot['Month'].map(month_dict)                
                ax[axy, axx].plot('Month','AveragePrice',data=df_plot, color='blue',marker='o')
                ax[axy, axx].set_title(str(cal_years[axx]) + ' ' + types[axy])
                ax[axy, axx].tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)
fig.suptitle('Season price fluctuation', size=16)
```

Would appreciate if anyone can point out why the code is not working as I expected. Many thanks

Comment: There is no `'Month'` key either in the dataset or anywhere defined by you, if I am right!? `Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'Date', 'AveragePrice', 'Total Volume', '4046', '4225',
       '4770', 'Total Bags', 'Small Bags', 'Large Bags', 'XLarge Bags', 'type',
       'year', 'region'],
      dtype='object')`

Comment: apologies I missed one line of code that creates the 'Month' field in the dataframe, which I have added back to the question already

Comment: Are you sure about `df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index).month`? because I tried `print(df['Month'])` and the entire column is nothing but `1`

Comment: I am pretty sure. I checked it with df.head()